# Explicit wait is not working in my case

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I've written below code for explicit wait in selenium but somehow it is not working... can anybody suggest what is wrong in my code.

```
public void waitForElementToBePresent(WebElement locator) {
    waitForElement(locator);
}

public WebElement waitForElement(WebElement locatorname) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    return (WebElement) wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(locatorname));
}

public static Function<WebDriver, WebElement> presenceOfElementLocated(final WebElement locatorname) {
    return new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return (locatorname);
        }

    };
}
```

Then where ever I need to wait for an element I am just calling:

```
waitForElementToBePresent(locatorName);
```

Answer (score 2):

Reason why your code is not working:

- Because you have passed element as `WebElement` so before waiting for that element, code must be start looking for that and fails. Instead of passing it as `WebElement` you should take it as an instance of `By.class`.

  ```
  public void presenceOfElementLocated(By elementLocator) {
  new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout)
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(elementLocator));
  }
  ```